# startEditingCell for AgGridReact not working with custom cell editor component

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-react

I have a scenario in which I have to mount render AgGridReact which is having a custom cell editor component. I am unable to use startEditingCell for editing the cell. The value is not populating in the grid.

```
const columnDefs = [
{
cellClassRules : { <some classes>},
cellEditor : 'customInput',
cellEditorParams : {
<some params>
},
cellStyle :{<some styles>},
editable : <method>,
singleClickEdit: true,
tooltipValueGetter: <method>,
valueGetter:<method>,
valueSetter:<method>,
width:100
}
];

return (
 <AgGridReact 
        columnDefs={columnDefinitions}
        frameworkComponents :{
           customInput : <React forwardref component>
           }
)
```

Here, react component(hooks component) have some validations on the data entered. So, in my tests I want to use startEditingCell to set the value so that  the hooks will be triggered and the validations will happen. I am unable to do that.

Can anybody suggest a solution on how to cover this case?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I have found out the solution for my question. AgGrid will render the custom cellEditor component only if we put the corresponding cell to editing mode. I have put the cell to editing mode by using startEditingCell with the params colKey and rowIndex and hence my component got rendered and was able to test further